# Spring Boot CRITICAL Vulnerability

Tags: spring

I'm running a vulnerability check on my project and it seems that spring has a vulnerability on **spring-core-5.3.21.jar** package:

[image]

```
>     <parent>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>         <version>2.7.1</version>
>     </parent>
```

If I check maven repo on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core it is the latest version and doesn't show any vulnerability.

I cannot have known vulnerabilities on the project. What do I do to remove this CVE?

Comment: What's the Vulnerability?

Comment: CVE-2016-1000027  suppress

Pivotal Spring Framework through 5.3.16 suffers from a potential remote code execution (RCE) issue if used for Java deserialization of untrusted data. Depending on how the library is implemented within a product, this issue may or not occur, and authentication may be required. NOTE: the vendor's position is that untrusted data is not an intended use case. The product's behavior will not be changed because some users rely on deserialization of trusted data.

Comment: I would then argue that - as long as you don't deserialize untrusted data using Java's deserialization framework of course - you should be ok and suppress this warning

Answer (score 3):

**Introduction**
It's a critical vulnerability CVE-2016-1000027 in Spring-web project
The Spring Framework  Javadoc describes HttpInvokerServiceExporter as a “Servlet-API-based HTTP request handler that exports the specified service bean as HTTP invoker service endpoint, accessible via an HTTP invoker proxy.” To the layperson, this essentially means that a client can execute specific methods exposed by the creator of the server application.

**Description from CVE**
Pivotal Spring Framework 4.1.4 suffers from a potential remote code execution (RCE) issue if used for Java deserialization of untrusted data. Depending on how the library is implemented within a product, this issue may or not occur, and authentication may be required.

**Explanation**

The org.springframework:spring-web package is vulnerable to deserialization of untrusted data leading to Remote Code Execution (RCE). The readRemoteInvocation method in HttpInvokerServiceExporter.class does not properly verify or restrict untrusted objects prior to deserializing them. An attacker can exploit this vulnerability by sending malicious requests containing crafted objects, which when deserialized, execute arbitrary code on the vulnerable system.

**Conclusion**: Check if you project is using HttpInvokerServiceExport to do java deserialisation.
If yes: try to eliminate the usage of org.springframework.remoting from your project
if no: You can  discuss with your security team establishing that your project is not prone to this vulneribility and leave it as is.

I have used fasterxml's jackson to do deserialization instead of java deserialization which makes my project not prone to this vulneribility.